# Safely deleting an aurora read replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have an aurora cluster with one writer and two readers. I would like to delete one reader.

If I simply right click and hit delete replica, it does not cleanly terminate connections but instead errors out clients trying to connect to the reader endpoint.

How do you delete a read replica without dropping connections or erroring out connections to the reader endpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found is to create a custom endpoint using the AWS CLI

```
aws rds create-db-cluster-endpoint --db-cluster-identifier AURORA-CLUSTER-NAME \
    --db-cluster-endpoint-identifier active-readers --endpoint-type reader
```

This creates an endpoint serving all your readers. Then, when you want to take a reader offline, first you take it out of the endpoint load balancer by removing it either on the cli or console, then wait for connections to wrap up, then finally delete the box.

The endpoint will pick up new readers automatically as well.